# Android SDK updating issue

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

i am new to android when i select window-android sdk and click i got error like this.. Expected verb after global parameters but found 'sdk' instead.
 thnxs in advance

Comment: Tell us more about your system, eg. OS, IDE, where did you click, ...

Comment: window xp,eclipse helios,In eclipse menu when i click Window-sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your ADT Plugins and try it again and this may solve the problem.